# When using Google Cloud Dataflow flex templates, is it possible to use a multi-command CLI to run a job?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've read through the Google Cloud Dataflow (python SDK v2.40) documents on creating a Flex Template for a single job. All examples and documentation I have found map a single python file to a single pipeline. However, I'd like to include a single python file that I can use to encapsulate multiple pipelines to allow a more modular and documentable set of pipelines. I'd like to minimize the number of separate images I create to run multiple pipelines. One approach that I would normally use is to have a multi-command command line interface like:

```
pipeline_script.py pipeline1
```

for pipeline 1.

```
pipeline_script.py pipeline2
```

for pipeline 2, and so on.

I see a single environment variable, `FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_OPTIONS`, that might be useful, but the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/configuring-flex-templates#set_required_dockerfile_environment_variables) is not clear on how it could help in my use case.

In summary, I have multiple dataflow pipelines that I'd like to run from a single Flex Template image. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's a hard restriction to limit a given image to a flex template. But each image maps to a given main file as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates#create_and_build_a_container_image).

So, if you are able to update your main file to run different pipelines based on metadata provided, you might be able to use the same image for multiple pipelines.